# Why doesn't createRadialGradient work on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

I'm working with the canvas tag of HTML5 and JavaScript to access the canvas methods and properties.

This code works on Chrome but it doesn't work on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/BD3xA/.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It works for me on Firefox 7.0.

Comment: It also works on Firefox 6.0. Can you clarify what exactly "doesn't work" and how? *Does your version of Firefox support the `<canvas>` element?*

Comment: I have firefox 7.0.1, when I use plain colors it works fine. Do I have to enable some functionality on my firefox to be able to see radialgradient?

Answer (score 0):

createRadialGradient works on Firefox, but addColorStop does not work completely - and will throw an exception if you pass in a transparency along with your color.

For example, after you create a radial gradient:

```
var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(centerX,centerY,outRadius,centerX,centerY,outRadius+pad);
var colorOut="rgba(100,200,100,0.7)";
grad.addColorStop(0,'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
grad.addColorStop(0.01,colorOut);
```

The above works great on chrome, but will not work on FF because of the 0.7 in the rgba color.

So, I use something like:

```
colorOut= ($.browser.mozilla)?'#D88':'rgba(200,100,100,0.7);';
```

This doesn't make gradients look quite so nice on FF, but functions.

Of course, you should cache that $.browser.mozilla earlier - make a var IS_MOZILLA = $.browser.mozilla; and then just use that (so that you minimize class calls... as saving every computation in complex drawing calls is important).